Is there yaml container definition specification for GCE COS image somewhere?
I'm using GCE VM with COS image running a container. To make it work with Terraform I'm using a terraform-google-modules/container-vm/google and then pass it as matadata key gce-container-declaration like this:
module "vm_container" {
  source         = "terraform-google-modules/container-vm/google"
  version        = "~> 3.1"
  restart_policy = "Always"
  volumes = [
    {
      name = "dotenv"
      hostPath = {
        path = "/etc/${var.secret_id}"
      }
    },
  ]
  container = {
    image = var.image_url
    volumeMounts = [
      {
        mountPath = "/var/www/.env"
        name      = "dotenv"
        readOnly  = true
      },
    ]
    env = [
      {
        name  = "DATABASE_URL"
        value = local.database_url
      },
    ]
  }
}


resource "google_compute_instance" "vm" {
  name                      = "vm-${terraform.workspace}-${substr(md5(format("%s%s", module.vm_container.metadata_value, data.template_file.cloudinit_config.rendered)), 0, 5)}"
  project                   = local.project_id
  machine_type              = "n1-standard-1"
  zone                      = local.zone
  allow_stopping_for_update = true
  desired_status            = "RUNNING"

  tags = ["allow-iap-ssh"]

  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = module.vm_container.source_image
    }
  }

  metadata = {
    enable-oslogin            = "TRUE"
    google-logging-enabled    = "true"
    gce-container-declaration = module.vm_container.metadata_value
    user-data                 = data.template_file.cloudinit_config.rendered
  }

  network_interface {
    network    = local.network_self_link
    subnetwork = local.subnetwork_self_link
  }

  service_account {
    scopes = ["cloud-platform"]
    email  = local.service_account_email
  }
}

I tried to to search for the actual allowed fields in container declaration in GCP docs, but I could not find any example involving yaml definition. There seems to be no specification of how should yaml be generated and what is allowed and not allowed inside. All my knowledge about what can I specify if from few examples of this terraform module. There are examples with gcloud command parameters all over the place but not with yaml.
Am I missing something here or there is no spec? Or maybe I should translate 1:1 those gcloud examples somehow to yaml?
Thanks

You have detail here on the options, but not on the YAML. What I usually do, I configure what i want on the console, click on the button "equivalent code" and get the metadata values for the container definition. Stupid, but functional!

@guillaumeblaquiere I guess I can also use json info about VM and do something like $ cat gce_vm.json | jq -r '.metadata.items[] | select(.key == "gce-container-declaration") | .value' to get the yaml. But still it is super strange that there is no actual spec. How should I know if I should use spec.containers instead of spec.container if there can only be one container with COS image. Maybe this is yaml schema as with k8s pod container? It definitely looks similar to it imo.
